L2 bounds for fem local basis functions
In a paper on Discontinuous Galerkin, the authors state that the following estimate can be proved using a simple scaling argument:
$$||\nabla\phi||_{L^2(K)}^2 \le C h_K^{d-2}$$
where $\phi$ is any local (Lagrange) nodal basis in the element $K$, $d=1,2,3$ is the spatial dimension and $C$ is a mesh-independent constant.
To prove this, one can start by using the affine mapping $x=h_K\hat{x}$ from the physical element to the reference element:
$$ ||\nabla\phi||_{L^2(K)}^2 =  h_K^{d-2} ||\hat{\nabla} \hat{\phi} ||_{L^2(\hat{K})}^2 $$
but how to prove the bound $||\hat{\nabla} \hat{\phi} ||_{L^2(\hat{K})}^2  \le C$ ? And is it also true for $||\hat{\phi}|_{L^2(\hat{K})}^2 $ and $||\hat{\nabla}^2\hat{\phi}||_{L^2(\hat{K})}^2 $? I would appreciate any references where such estimates are shown for Lagrange-type basis and Hermite-type basis.

The inequality at the top is known as an "inverse inequality". Basically, it says that if you squeeze a shape function from the reference cell into a cell of size $h$ (relative to the reference cell), keeping its height the same, then the gradients need to become $1/h$ times larger. Its square is then $h^{-2}$ times larger and if you integrate this over a domain of area/volume $h^d$, you get exactly the second equality.
The bound
$$||\hat{\nabla} \hat{\phi} ||_{L^2(\hat{K})}^2  \le C$$
really is not so much of a bound, but should have been written as
$$C := ||\hat{\nabla} \hat{\phi} ||_{L^2(\hat{K})}^2.$$
The shape function $\hat\phi$ is what it is, and so is its $H^1$ seminorm. If you want to be slightly more generic, then you would define $C$ is the maximum of the right hand sides over all of the shape functions on the reference cell.
